# On client side get value of first cell in RadGrid row upon row creation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

My grid has an `OnRowCreated` event as such:

```
function grdBookingItems_rowCreated(sender, eventArgs) {
               console.log(eventArgs.get_gridDataItem().get_element());
            }
```

But obviously this isn't what it's supposed to look like in the end. What I want to do is to create a click event for the last  on the row, whose argument is created from the text found in the first  element.

Every row looks sort of like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td><div class="button"></div></td>
</tr>
```

And so I want to do something like storing the tr in a Jquery variable and then using its children. But how do I retrieve the tr?

The data I log to the console above looks like this:

```
<tr id="grdFoo_ctl00__0" class="rgRow">
```

But I haven't found from the Telerik RadGrid API how I am to retrieve a reference to the tr.

Comment: If you are looking for server side then check this link http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdusinggetitemsgetcolumnmethods.html

Comment: I prefer to do it client side, as that is where I'll have an easier time (I would assume) retrieving the numerical value (44 above).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I guess I solved it. Not sure if it's the prettiest way of doing things, but it works:

```
function grdBookingItems_rowCreated(sender, eventArgs) {
                var rowId = eventArgs.get_gridDataItem().get_element().id;
                var row = $("#" + rowId);
                var firstId = row.children().first().html();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the event arguments a chance? THe **dataKeyValues** collection can help: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-onrowcreated.html. Note that you would need to add the needed fields to the **ClientDataKeyNames** collection of the **MasterTableView** http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-extract-key-values-client-side.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
    function RowCreated(sender, args) {
        var $trJaueryVariable = $(args.get_gridDataItem().get_element());
        //Access your tr in a Jquery variable 
    }
```

I have already applied above code in [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/get-radgrid-cell-value-on-button-click) code and it works for me.

Let me know if any concern.